# Prevent "/login" to redirect to "/wp-login"

Tags: redirect, login

A client has asked me to exlude "/login" as they want to have the url to lead elsewhere (to a remote system). When typing this url it automatically redirects to "/wp-login". How can I remove / prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hosting on Apache you could do this in your .htaccess file by adding the following before any of the Wordpress rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule ^login$ http://example.com/ [NC,L,R]
```

Just replace "http://example.com/" with your clients remote system URL.